# python - error while sorting csv by column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to sort a .csv file by multiple columns, I'm using pandas, this is the .csv file:

```
col1;col2;col3;col4;col5
6943000;11;1.0;2016-01-01 15:30:31;?
6943000;19;1.0;2016-01-01 15:38:07;?
6943000;13;1.0;2016-01-01 15:54:27;?
6942992;10;1.0;2016-01-01 00:52:59;?
6942993;8;1.0;2016-01-01 12:08:36;?
.....
```

I should order it by col1 and col4, this is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
df = df.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col4'])
df.to_csv('sorted.csv', index=False)
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python\Scripts\provacsv.py", line 3, in <module>
    df = df.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col4'])   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4411, in sort_values
    stacklevel=stacklevel)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1379, in
_get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key) KeyError: 'col1'
```

So it fails for `col1`, but I'm not sure it's the right way to order col 4(timestamps)

Comment: Your csv is delimited by a semi-colon, use `df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep=';')`, currently all your columns are loading into a single column which is why it can't find that column

Comment: thanks, it worked! and timestamps were sorted too!

Comment: whenever we get error for column name try to traceback `df.columns` and check  are you using same column name present in this list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your csv is delimited by a semi-colon `';'`, by default the separator for `read_csv` is `','`, pass param `sep=';'`:

```
In[21]:
import io
t="""col1;col2;col3;col4;col5
6943000;11;1.0;2016-01-01 15:30:31;?
6943000;19;1.0;2016-01-01 15:38:07;?
6943000;13;1.0;2016-01-01 15:54:27;?
6942992;10;1.0;2016-01-01 00:52:59;?
6942993;8;1.0;2016-01-01 12:08:36;?"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=';')
df = df.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col4'])
df

[21]: 
      col1  col2  col3                 col4 col5
3  6942992    10   1.0  2016-01-01 00:52:59    ?
4  6942993     8   1.0  2016-01-01 12:08:36    ?
0  6943000    11   1.0  2016-01-01 15:30:31    ?
1  6943000    19   1.0  2016-01-01 15:38:07    ?
2  6943000    13   1.0  2016-01-01 15:54:27    ?
```

Also note that your timestamps are being interpreted as strings, if you want `datetime` `dtype` then tell `pandas` to parse them:

```
In[26]:

import io
t="""col1;col2;col3;col4;col5
6943000;11;1.0;2016-01-01 15:30:31;?
6943000;19;1.0;2016-01-01 15:38:07;?
6943000;13;1.0;2016-01-01 15:54:27;?
6942992;10;1.0;2016-01-01 00:52:59;?
6942993;8;1.0;2016-01-01 12:08:36;?"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=';', parse_dates=['col4'])
df = df.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col4'])
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 3 to 2
Data columns (total 5 columns):
col1    5 non-null int64
col2    5 non-null int64
col3    5 non-null float64
col4    5 non-null datetime64[ns]
col5    5 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 240.0+ bytes
```

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare I'm only doing this to simulate an in-memory text file